# Container name for media asset on Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services

How do I set the name of the container when creating an asset for Windows Azure Media Services?

Calling my [CloudMediaContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mediaservices.client.cloudmediacontext.aspx)  like this to create a new asset creates a new container in blob storage with the name "asset-[newGuid]" e.g. "asset-f230411a-22a0-4813-9187-4b815dbfdf12".

```
var assetName = "foobar";    
var asset = _mediaContext.Assets.Create(assetName, assetCreationOptions);
```

**Background info** on the call above by [Nick Drouin](http://blog-ndrouin.azurewebsites.net/?p=1261) (who works at MS on AMS)

> "Under the hood, the call above will: create an IAsset and add it to
>   the assets collection; create an IFileInfo to put in the asset; create
>   an AccessPolicy with write permission, request a SAS locator for the
>   asset container in Azure Storage using the AccessPolicy, upload the
>   file into your storage account, and finally revoke the SAS url."

**Question**
How do I control the name of the container?

Answer (score 6):

Currently Windows Azure Media Services is not allowing user to specify existing container name where asset will be created or specify custom name of new container . Please utilize http://azuremediaservices.uservoice.com/forums/88965-media-services-feature-suggestions to propose or vote for new feature suggestions.

Comment: Oh no that is such shame that it isn't already there. Will up vote it on there.