# Azure Media Services: How to change the naming convention of the containers

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services

Azure Media Services creates a storage container after a job is finished encoding a video file. The name of the container starts with `asset` followed by a unique identifier. Is it possible to configure this behavior so that I get to use a different naming convention?

There is a similar old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753073/container-name-for-media-asset-on-azure-media-services), but it was asked many years ago. I want to know if there has been a change since then.

Comment: Are you using .net sdk ? Or do you have to create a job on the portal?

Comment: I have post my answer， if you need further help, pls let me know.

Comment: I'm using the .NET SDK.

Comment: Pls read my answer, it should be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Creates or updates an Asset in the Media Services account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/assets/createorupdate) by rest api.

If you use .net sdk you can refer to [`CreateOutputAssetAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-tutorial-with-api#create-an-output-asset-to-store-the-result-of-a-job) method.

**Suggestion**

*Understand what the create job does, and then you can use the code to call the api to achieve it.*

## Related posts:

[Azure Media Services (v3) - specific output asset container name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647595/azure-media-services-v3-specific-output-asset-container-name)

Comment: Thanks Jason Pan!  You got it!